# How to create random-dot stereogram (RDS)?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand and code a python script that create a **random-dot stereogram (RDS)** from a depthmap and a random-dot generated pattern. From what I've understood, to create the illusion of depth, pixels are shifted so when we make them merge by changing focus the difference of shifting creates the illusion.

I put this into practice with **this depth map**:

[image: depth map star]

Here is **the result:**

[image]

But I don't understand why I can see on the result 2 objects, 1 star "close" to me and an other star "far" from me. And there is different possible results depending of how I focus my eyes.

I have read many things on the subject but I don't get it. Maybe the problem is my poor english or understanding of what I've read but I will appreciate some detailed explanations since there not that much technical explanations on the web about how to code this from scratch.

**Note:** I have tried with different size on shift and pattern and it doesn't seem to change anything

**Code:** (Tell me if you need other part of the code or some comment about how it work. I didn't clean it yet)

```
import os, sys
import pygame

def get_linked_point(depthmap, d_width, d_height, sep):
    """
    In this function we link each pixel in white in the depth map with the 
    coordinate of the shifted pixel we will need to create the illusion
    ex: [[x,y],[x_shifted,y]]

    :param sep: is the shift value in pixels
    """
    deptharray = pygame.PixelArray(depthmap)
    list_linked_point = []
    for x in range(d_width):
        for y in range(d_height):
            if deptharray[x][y] != 0x000000:
                list_linked_point.append([[x, y], [x+sep, y]])
    del deptharray
    return list_linked_point


def display_stereogram(screen, s_width, pattern, p_width, linked_points):
    """
    Here we fill the window with the pattern. Then for each linked couple of 
    point we make the shifted pixel [x_shifted,y] equal to the other one 
    [x,y]
    """
    x = 0
    while x < s_width:
        screen.blit(pattern, [x, 0])
        x += p_width
    pixAr = pygame.PixelArray(screen)
    for pair in linked_points:
        pixAr[pair[0][0], pair[0][1]] = pixAr[pair[1][0], pair[1][1]]
    del pixAr
```

Comment: The stereograms tag doesn't exist and I don't really find any appropriate tags. If I found some better one I will add them

Comment: To get help you will need to share code that does the logic of the bitmap shifting.

Comment: @NeilSlater Here is the code. But I think the problem is more about how to make it than a bug in the code. If you need some more details tell me. I just add what I thought was relevent to not make lmy post too long

Comment: Yes the problem may well be with how you have approached the maths after reading about the subject. But you did not explain what you have read, nor what you had done. It may not be possible to figure out what is wrong just from the images. I've done this project myself successfully some 20 years ago (in QBASIC :-), but sadly cannot remember enough about what I did to spot where you are going wrong.

Comment: @NeilSlater Okay I will try to add some comment to explain what I've did

Comment: @NeilSlater Should I add the math tag ? I understood how it work with 2 images like stereo pictures. But I think I miss something about RDS about pattern and shift of pixels, it still confuse in my brain

Comment: I think the problem is to do with maintaining the shift in pattern so far (total shift should be cumulative). It looks to me like to you are shifting according to current depth, but not maintaining that same total shift once you leave that depth - so when the "3D" viewpoint exits the star you are over-compensating (the distances between new points should be back to baseline, but overall the pattern should be shifted towards the left)

Comment: @NeilSlater "you are shifting according to current depth, but not maintaining that same total shift once you leave that depth" Yes it's exactly what I am doing. So I thought that by not shifting anymore when I will exist the star I will be back to the baseline. What do you mean by "overall the pattern should be shifted towards the left" ? edit: Oh wait, maybe I get it. I will try to modify my code

Comment: @NeilSlater After some quick modifications it seems much more better ! I think I understand now, what you mean and my mistake about how it works ! Since I am new on SO I don't know if I should write an answer to present the result after correction or if I should edit my question to add good stereogram I got after your help

Comment: I'm glad my idea helped. Please write an answer, as I could not see how to modify your Python. In general you should only modify the question to clarify it - make it easier to understand where the fault is. If you have a solution, then it is an answer, and we encourage self-answers.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you so much ! I can feel the satisfaction of understanding something new now :)

Comment: There's some good info (with C code) about making single image stereograms [here](http://www.techmind.org/stereo/stech.html). I haven't played with this stuff since the 90's, and like Neil, I've forgotten almost everything I once knew on the subject. But after seeing this question I had some fun writing some crude stereogram code using Numpy & PIL.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for the link ! There is definitly usefull information here. I don't know why it's so unknown among my generation (I am born in the 90's) because I think there is very funny things to do with it.

Comment: When they first appeared single image stereograms were a big craze, but they faded into obscurity when the novelty value wore off. Part of the problem is that a lot of people have difficulty seeing them, or they go cross-eyed and see them with the depth reversed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The problem *"I can see on the result 2 objects, 1 star "close" to me and an other star "far" from me"*** is due to the fact that I get the wrong approach when I try to generalize my understanding of stereograms made with 2 images to stereograms using repeated pattern.

To create 2 images stereograms you need to shift pixels of one image to make the depth illusion.

What was wrong in my approch is that I only shift pixels that should create the star. What I didn't get is that because RDS are made by repeated patterns, **shifting these pixels also create an opposite shifting with next patterns** creating an other star of the opposite depth.

To correct this I paired every point of the depth map (not only the white one) in order to come back to the base shifting amount after the end of the star.

**Here is the result:** [image: correct result]

**Code:** (This code is the previous one quickly modified after the help of Neil Slater so it's not clean yet. I will try to improve this)

```
def get_linked_point(depthmap, d_width, d_height, p_width, sep):
    """
    In this function we link each pixel in white in the depth map with the 
    coordinate of the shifted pixel we will need to create the illusion
    ex: [[x,y],[x_shifted,y]]

    :param sep: is the shift value in pixels
    """
    deptharray = pygame.PixelArray(depthmap)
    list_linked_point = []
    for x in range(d_width):
        for y in range(d_height):
            if deptharray[x][y] == 0x000000:
                list_linked_point.append([[x, y], [x+p_width, y]])
            else:
                list_linked_point.append([[x, y], [x-sep+p_width, y]])
    del deptharray
    return list_linked_point


def display_stereogram(screen, s_width, pattern, p_width, linked_points):
    """
    Here we fill the window with the pattern. Then for each linked couple of 
    point we make the shifted pixel [x_shifted,y] equal to the other one 
    [x,y]
    """
    x = 0
    while x < s_width:
        screen.blit(pattern, [x, 0])
        x += p_width
    pixAr = pygame.PixelArray(screen)
    for pair in linked_points:
        pixAr[pair[1][0], pair[1][1]] = pixAr[pair[0][0], pair[0][1]]
    del pixAr
```